# How to record audio from voice channel in discord.js voice v13?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, discord.js, pcm

I’m trying to record audio from a voice channel in discord using v13 of discord.js. Here is my code :

```js
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require("@discordjs/voice");
const fs = require("fs");
var { streams } = require("streams.js");

var voiceChannel = interaction.member.voice.channel;
streams[voiceChannel.id] = fs.createWriteStream("test.pcm");


const connection = await joinVoiceChannel({
                channelId: voiceChannel.id,
                guildId: interaction.guild.id,
                adapterCreator: interaction.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
                selfDeaf: false
            });
const audio = connection.receiver.subscribe(`${interaction.user.id}`, {encoding: "utf-8"});
audio.pipe(streams[voiceChannel.id]);
```

then the stop command :

```js
…
streams[voiceChannel.id].close();
delete streams[voiceChannel.id];
```

And when I convert the pcm to wav using `ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 44.1k -ac 2 -i test.pcm file.wav`, it returns a short audio without my voice but the noise "ffffffffffff"
Why ?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```js
import {opus} from 'prism-media'

const receiver = connection.receiver.subscribe(userId, { end: { behavior: EndBehaviorType.AfterSilence, duration: 100 } });
const decoder = new opus.Decoder({ frameSize: 960, channels: 2, rate: 48000 });
const stream = receiver.pipe(decoder).pipe(createWriteStream("./test.pcm"))
stream.on("finish", () => {
    exec("ffmpeg -y -f s16le -ar 48k -ac 2 -i test.pcm test.mp3")
})
```

Comment: What module is new opus.Decoder from ?

Comment: `npm install prism`

Comment: I´m getting this error because of prism opus decoder in discordjs v14

`node:internal/validators:98
      throw new ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE(name, `>= ${min} && <= ${max}`, value);
      ^

RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "sourceEnd" is out of range. It must be >= 0 && <= 3. Received 8
    at validateOffset (node:buffer:115:3)
    at Buffer.compare (node:buffer:901:5)
    at Decoder._transform (/opt/polimorfia/node_modules/prism-media/dist/opus/Decoder.js:19:19)
    at Transform._write (node:internal/streams/transform:175:8)

  code: 'ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE'`

Comment: Interesting error. Maybe you need to find prism version that supports v13?